# Python inheritance: Concatenating with super __str__

Tags: python, inheritance

I'd like to have a child class' `__str__` implementation add to the base implementation:

```
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return "this"

class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return super(B, self) + " + that"
```

This, however, produces a type error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'super' and 'str'

Is there any way to get `str(B())` return `"this + that"`?

Comment: Not that this is your issue, but in Python 3 you can just write `super()`, no need for the old 2.x syntax `super(B, self)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do `super(B, self).__str__()`.  `super` refers to the parent class; you are not calling any methods.

Comment: In python 2, you need your parent class to subclass object.  See http://isbullsh.it/2012/03/Class-inheritance-in-python/.

Comment: In Python 3, `super().__str__()` is much clearer and shorter.

Comment: Isn't `str(super())` even shorter?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, well – yes. But does it work? No.

Answer (score 4):

class B should be:

```
class B(A):
def __str__(self):
    return super(B, self).__str__() + ' + that
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is some working code. What you needed was to

1) subclass object, so that super works as expected, and

2) Use `__str__()` when concatenating your string.

```
class A(object):
  def __str__(self):
    return "this"


class B(A):

  def __str__(self):
    return super(B, self).__str__() + " + that"

print B()
```

Note: `print B()` calls `b.__str__()` under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

For python 2, as other have posted.

```
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "this"

class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return super(B, self).__str__() + " + that"
```

For python 3 the syntax is simplified. `super` requires no arguments to work correctly.

```
class A():
    def __str__(self):
        return "this"

class B(A):
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + " + that"
```