# Call super() on __str__ method in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, class

I've been playing around with OOP for a couple of days, and now I'm trying to understand how the `super()` method works.

The problem I'm having is that I would like to call my `__str__` function from another class and inherit the things in the superclass.

I read [Python inheritance: Concatenating with super __str__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062946/python-inheritance-concatenating-with-super-str) but that solution did not work.

The code I am having is this

```
class Taxi:

    def __init__(self, drivername, onduty, cities):
        self.drivername = drivername
        self.onduty = onduty
        self.cities = cities

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.drivername, self.onduty, self.cities)

class Type(Taxi):

    def __init__(self, drivername, onduty, cities, model):
        super().__init__(drivername, onduty, cities)
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        super(Taxi, self).__str__() #Tried as well with super().__str__()
        return '{}'.format(self.model)

mymodel = Type('Foobar', True, 'Washington', 'Volvo')
print(mymodel)
```

So I want the `__str__` function in the Taxi class to return the given values, and then the string class in the subclass to return the last value.

How do I do it?

Comment: `super(Taxi, self).__str__()` returns a string, which you're completely ignoring. You can't just call it, you need to *do something with the result*, as shown in the other post you say doesn't help.

Comment: I am not sure why you got the downvote. It's a clear question, however elementary, and you clearly put some effort into figuring it out yourself.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: agreed. Many tutorials only show examples of calling `super().__init__(...)`, which does not have a return value. So this confusion is totally understandable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are completely ignoring the result of your call to the superclass definition of `__str__`. You probably want something along the lines of

```
def __str__(self):
    prefix = super().__str__()
    return '{} {}'.format(prefix, self.model)
```

Calling `super().__str__()` does not do anything magical. It is just another method call, so you need to treat it that way. The return value will not magically absorb itself into your method unless you make it so.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use **f-strings**.

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.model}'
```

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't answer the question. It is just a more convenient way of doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Apologies, I am still learning the ins of python. Why so?

Comment: Because the question is about how to properly call `super`. Formatting the result is an incidental part of the example. So *just* changing the formatting without actually solving the `super` part misses the core of the question.